# Attempting to link an image button to a class Android

Tags: android

Please forgive me i am new to programming for android. I am attempting to link a ImageButton to a class called crafting which then starts a xml file called crafting within that class. The button does not appear to do anything in the avd but i am struggling to see where my error is.

Here is the code:

The mainActivity:

```
package cf.angryman.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void SetupCraftingButton() {
        ImageButton craftingButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.crafting);
        craftingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Crafting.class));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The crafting class:

```
package cf.angryman.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Crafting extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crafting);
    }

}
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="341dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/crafting"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/workbench" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope you can help!

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Could you post your button's XML?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the XML

Answer (score 1):

`SetupCraftingButton()` never gets called.

Call it within your first `onCreate() { ... }` one line after the `setContentView(R.layout.button_test)` and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found your error.
In your MainActivity.class change

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Crafting.class));
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Crafting.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and add

```
final Context context = this;
```

below your public void SetupCraftingButton()

Then add this

```
import android.content.Context;
```

to your list of imports

Additionally as Stephan (you can accept his answer for this, not mine) pointed out you haven't called SetupCraftingButton().

So your code will look like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_test);
        SetupCraftingButton();
    }
```

So your code in your SetupCraftingButton() will look like this

```
public void SetupCraftingButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        ImageButton craftingButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.crafting);
        craftingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, Crafting.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: The button still isn't functioning, any other ideas?